Help interpreting Residuals vs Fitted Plot with 2 clusters
What would this residual vs fitted plot indicate?

It was generated by plotting a multiple linear regression model that was fitted on several variables that are continuous and categorical. I don't understand why there's two clusters around 0.5 and 0.9. Does this indicate that there's a violation in the assumptions of homoscedasticity, linearity, or independence? My dataset has lot of similar values for each corresponding test subject. For example, there are many males that have similar continuous values.
Please let me know if I need to provide more data and I will edit my original question.

no; it simply indicates that there are two clusters in your X values*; perhaps males vs females. This is unrelated to the assumptions of linear regression, which place essentially no constraints on your X variables. (*at least, there are two clusters when the X values are projected onto the subspace given by your regression coefficients).
